# Google Cloud Logging API with Apps Script - delete logs - The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

Using Apps Script, I need to delete the Stackdriver logs of a particular Google Cloud Project.  This should be possible to do with Apps Script and the Cloud Logging REST API, using a `DELETE` request.  Apps Script `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options)` can use the `DELETE` method.  The code below is returning response code: 404.  I was previously getting response code: 400, but now it's accepting the URL structure, but it just can't find the URL.  If the URL needs a log ID, then I'm not sure where to get the log ID.  I want to delete *all* logs in the project, not just a particular one.

Error Message:

```
The requested URL was not found on this server.
```

Code:

```
function deleteStackDriverLogs(po) {
  var httpRz,options,url;

  /*
    po.id = GCP project ID - https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard
  */

  options = {};

  options.method = "delete";
  options.muteHttpExceptions = true;
  options.headers = {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()};
  options.contentType = "application/json";

  url = 'https://logging.googleapis.com/v2/';

  options.payload = JSON.stringify({
    logName: 'projects/' + po.id + "/logs/*"
  });

  httpRz = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
  Logger.log('response code: ' + httpRz.getResponseCode());

  //Logger.log('httpRz.getAllHeaders(): ' + JSON.stringify(httpRz.getAllHeaders()))
  //Logger.log(httpRz.getContentText())

}

function testDlet() {
  deleteStackDriverLogs({"id":"project-id-your-GCP-id-here"});


}
```

Documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/logs/delete

If just a URL without the payload is used, then I get response code 404 with no explanation.

I've tried many variations of the url.

```
url = 'https://logging.googleapis.com/v2/logName={projects/' + po.id + '}';//404
url = 'https://logging.googleapis.com/v2/logName=projects/' + po.id + '/';//404
url = 'https://logging.googleapis.com/v2/logName=projects/' + po.id;//404
url = 'https://logging.googleapis.com/v2/logName=projects/' + po.id + '/logs/*/';//400
url = 'https://logging.googleapis.com/v2/logName=projects/' + po.id + '/logs/';//404
```

The documentation states that the Log ID must be URL-encoded. But, I'm not sure what to use for the Log ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to delete the logs of the stackdriver using Google Apps Script.

For this, how about this answer?

#### Modification points:

- In this case, please retrieve the log name for deleting the logs.

  - You can retrieve `logName` using the method "logs.list" in Could Logging API v2.
- Please use `logName` as the path of the endpoint.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function deleteStackDriverLogs(po) {

  // --- I added below script.
  const endpoint = `https://logging.googleapis.com/v2/projects/${po.id}/logs`;
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(endpoint, {headers: {authorization: `Bearer ${ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}`}});
  const obj = JSON.parse(res.getContentText());
  const logName = obj.logNames.filter(e => e.includes("console_logs"))[0];
  /// ---

  var httpRz,options,url;

  /*
    po.id = GCP project ID - https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard
  */

  options = {};

  options.method = "delete";
  options.muteHttpExceptions = true;
  options.headers = {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()};

  url = 'https://logging.googleapis.com/v2/' + logName;  // Modified

  httpRz = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
  Logger.log('response code: ' + httpRz.getResponseCode());

  //Logger.log('httpRz.getAllHeaders(): ' + JSON.stringify(httpRz.getAllHeaders()))
  //Logger.log(httpRz.getContentText())

}
```

#### Note:

- This is a simple modification for your script. So please modify this for your actual situation.
- This modified script supposes that you have already been able to use Could Logging API v2.
- In this case, please use this script with V8.

#### References:

- [Method: logs.list](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/logs/list)
- [Method: logs.delete](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/logs/delete)

Comment: @Alan Wells Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.